# How to split string in words and non-words

Tags: java

I am looking for an elegant way of splitting a string in words and non-words, where a "word" is defined by some regular expression (for instance, `[a-zA-Z]+`).

Input is a string, output should be a list of word and non-word substrings in order. For instance:

```
"A! B C, d." -> Arrays.asList("A", "! ", "B", " ", "C", ", ","d", ".")
```

Here's my take:

```
public static String WORD_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z]+";

public static List<String> splitString(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile(WORD_PATTERN);
    Matcher wordMatcher = wordPattern.matcher(str);

    List<String> splitString = new ArrayList<>();

    int endOfLastWord = 0;

    while(wordMatcher.find())
    {
        int startOfNextWord = wordMatcher.start();
        int endOfNextWord = wordMatcher.end();

        if (startOfNextWord > endOfLastWord) {
            String nextNonWord = str.substring(endOfLastWord, startOfNextWord);
            splitString.add(nextNonWord);
        }

        String nextWord = str.substring(startOfNextWord, endOfNextWord);
        splitString.add(nextWord);
        endOfLastWord = endOfNextWord;
    }

    if (endOfLastWord < str.length()) {
        String lastNonWord = str.substring(endOfLastWord);
        splitString.add(lastNonWord);
    }
    return splitString;
}
```

This does not feel elegant, I think there should be a better way which I'm just not aware of.

I am not looking to improve the code above, so please don't refer to [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I've only posted it to avoid "what have you tried so far" comments.

I am looking for a more concise and elegant way, ideally only using standard Java packages.

Comment: Does the order of elements in the resulting list have to be consistent with the original input text?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Yes, the order must be consistent. Concatenation in order must produce the original string.

Comment: @Downvoter Please provide reason for downvote.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele, since you removed your answer, here is the same logic I had provided for your merge method but without the `Stream` on [ideone](https://ideone.com/gVdzf9), it do the same (but probably more performant this way).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to capture both word and non-word with an optional content :

```
(\w*)(\W*)
```

- **\w** : [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- **\W** : [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

Example with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wXcbLs/1/)

For each match, take both capture groups, check if there is a value captured (length > 0) and add the value to the list.

This give a nice and simple solution like :

```
public List<String> splitWord(String s){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)(\\W*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){
        Optional.of(m.group(1)).filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).ifPresent(result::add);
        Optional.of(m.group(2)).filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()).ifPresent(result::add);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note : the `Optional` is ... optional but I am trying to improve myself on it. It will simply check if the group have a value that is not empty and will add it to the list.

And the result formatted to match your example

```
"abc def" -> Arrays.asList("abc", " ", "def")
"a.b. c" -> Arrays.asList("a", ".", "b", ". ", "c")
"a.b." -> Arrays.asList("a", ".", "b", ".")
".aa" -> Arrays.asList(".", "aa")
"." -> Arrays.asList(".")
"a" -> Arrays.asList("a")
".." -> Arrays.asList("..")
```

Here is the example with the formatting method in [ideone](https://ideone.com/vbwtol)